# Java: Printing the position of a number in Array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that prints the number in X position (using arrays). The thing is that if the position I input is larger than the sequence of numbers (it ends when I input -1).

For example, I want to print the number in the position 7, this is the sequence of numbers:

1 2 3 -1

I should get a message that says "Incorrect position", because there is a 0 in position 7.

Otherwise, if position 7 has a number, I will print the position and the number.

My problem is a little bit weird, because the first sequence is read fine and it prints the correct sentence, but if I continue inputting, it will always read the position of the last sequence I used, so that is not very useful. I attach the **description of the exercise**:

Write a program that, given several test cases, each one composed by an integer number i and a sequence of natural numbers x1, x2, …, xn, prints each xi.

Input

Input has several cases. Each case begins with an integer number i, followed by a sequence x1, …, xn ended with −1.

Output

For each case, if the position i is correct, print the content of i as it is shown in the examples. Otherwise, print “Incorrect position.”.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int pos;
int [] seq = new int [20];
int i;
int count = 0;


while (true) {
    pos = sc.nextInt();
    for(i = 1; i < seq.length; i++) {
        seq[i] = sc.nextInt();
            if (seq[i] == -1) {
                break;
            }               
        count++;
    }
    if (pos > count) {
        System.out.println("Posicio incorrecta" + ".");
    } else {
        System.out.println("A la posicio " + pos + " hi ha un " + seq[pos] + ".");
    }           
}
```

Comment: hint: the bug has to do with `count`

Comment: To have in the loop an array again filled with zeroes, place `int[] seq = new seq[20];` _inside_ the loop. It might be nice to have at the start of a loop step everything initially have a right value.

Answer (score 0):

```
//  hint:look at count in your code else its better to determine the scope of variables. You can uncomment the sysout line to understand better. happycoding :)
 while (true) {
            int pos;
            int i;
            int count = 0;
            int [] seq = new int [20];
            pos = sc.nextInt();
            for(i = 1; i < seq.length; i++) {
                seq[i] = sc.nextInt();
                if (seq[i] == -1) {
                    break;
                }
                count++;
            }
            //System.out.println(pos + " "+ count);
            if (pos > count) {
                System.out.println("Posicio incorrecta" + ".");
            } else {
                System.out.println("A la posicio " + pos + " hi ha un " + seq[pos] + ".");
            }
            // for(i = 1; i < seq.length; i++)
            //System.out.print(seq[i]+" ");
        }
```